# Django ORM: Join two tables using a linked table

Tags: django, django-orm

I want to integrate a function `has_permission(self, permission_name)` in the class `Profile`.
For this I want to do make a ORM statement which returns a list of permission names.

The data model is:

- **1** User has **1** Profile (extends Django's User model)
- Each **Profile** is assigned to one **ProfileGroup**.
  However, different **Profiles** can belong to the same **ProfileGroup**.
- Each **ProfileGroup** can have one or more **ProfilePermissions**. Groups can have the same subsets of **ProfilePermissions**. The Link-Table **GroupPermissions** handles this using two `ForeignKeys` instead of a `ManyToMany` relation.

My `models.py` looks like this:

```
class ProfileGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)


class ProfilePermission(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)


class GroupPermissions(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(ProfileGroup, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    permission = models.ForeignKey(ProfilePermission, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['group', 'permission'], name='Unique')
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Group "{self.group.name}" has permission "{self.permission.name}"'


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(ProfileGroup, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Profile of {self.user.username}'

    def has_permission(self, permission_name):
        return True
```

The function `has_permission` (in the `Profile` class) should check if the permission `permission` is included in the list of Permissions. I tried it with

`list_of_permissions = GroupPermissions.objects.filter(group=self.group)`

But this returns a list of `ProfilePermission`. What I want is a list of names of the permission (`permission.name`).

So I have to join the two Tables `GroupPermissions` and `ProfilePermission`. I found things as `prefetch_related` and `select_related` but this does not work as I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your question directly,

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(ProfileGroup, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Profile of {self.user.username}'

    def has_permission(self, permission_name):
        return GroupPermissions.objects.filter(group=self.group, permission__name=permission_name).exists()
```

But... My advice to you is to not try to reinvent the wheel. django.contib.auth has already groups and permissions, just use them ;-)

Comment: If I got it right, there is no direct link between groups and permissions there. I want a user to be assigned to exactly one group and this group then assigns the user the appropriate permissions.

Comment: @michaelT there is a link, Group from contrib.auth.models can have multiple Permissions assigned